# Knitting errors with RMarkdown after upgrading to RStudio 1.2

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr

Yesterday I upgraded to RStudio 1.2. Today I'm trying to knit a file that has been sitting unchanged for a month and getting an error very early in the process.

I'm inferring that it was the upgrade because a) I don't know why else it would have happened and b) I find some documented issues at GitHub where people had these errors last year (presumably with the dev version of RStudio). I'm not finding anything about people having the issue now that 1.2 is productionized.

I have another RMarkdown file that is scheduled and runs on a server everyday. I am able to knit that file. So it's not broken on everything, just something about this file but I don't know where to get started on troubleshooting.

> pandoc.exe: WEEKLY_DATA_QUALITY_CHECK.utf8.md: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
>   Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   running command '"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS WEEKLY_DATA_QUALITY_CHECK.utf8.md --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash+smart --output WEEKLY_DATA_QUALITY_CHECK.html --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --template "C:\Users\cumphlet\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\rmarkdown\rmd\h\default.html" --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable "theme:bootstrap" --include-in-header "C:\Users\cumphlet\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp4sVay6\rmarkdown-str34d0484814d7.html" --mathjax --variable "mathjax-url:https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"' had status 1 
>   Execution halted

I am able to run all of the chunks in pieces. The error happens before chunk code is even evaluated.

Comment: Do you know at what line in your `.Rmd` that the script is failing? If so, could you post it so that we know what functions are being called?

Comment: it's not even processing the code it seems. there's no reference to processing a chunk. it fails before that

Comment: Interesting. I think that `WEEKLY_DATA_QUALITY_CHECK.utf8.md` is an intermediate file that gets created when you start knitting, but then gets cleaned up when the final `.md` is created. What if you try installing the previous version of RStudio? Does that fix your issue? That way you know for sure that it's the new version that is the culprit

Comment: that's something I will try eventually but doesn't fit well into my schedule today as I'm doing multiple things in RStudio and want to be working continually... i'm also concerned that it could end up with some other problems if i end up with some packages that don't play nicely.

Comment: by bad file, are you referring to WEEKLY_DATA_QUALITY_CHECK.utf8.md? I'm not sure what details I can provide, this is not a file that I'm creating. I am running WEEKLY_DATA_QUALITY_CHECK.Rmd and attempting to knit to WEEKLY_DATA_QUALITY_CHECK.html

Comment: It is .Rmd. This is a file I’ve knitted previously, the name hasn’t changed.